# Glide + CollapsingToolbarLayout strange behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-glide

I'm facing a strange behavior when using CollapsingToolbarLayout, Toolbar and an ImageView embedded.
Here is my code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/bla"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_kids_profile_pic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And the Glide builder:

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(file)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(profilePicture);
```

Before setting the image via Glide, the Toolbar behavior works exact as it should, in my case "pinned". After setting the image, the Toolbar layout goes missing and the image takes place (after scrolling up).
Some pics to clarify:

Before setting the picture:
[image: Before scrolling][image][image][image]

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens because `CollapsingToolbarLayout` extends `FrameLayout`.
In `FrameLayout` the last view in the view hierarchy is the one on the top (if you haven't changed it in code), so it's normal that your `ImageView` covers the `Toolbar`. To solve this "issue" you have just to change the order:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/bla"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_kids_profile_pic"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Before you set the image via `Glide` the `ImageView`'s background was transparent, this is why you could see the `Toolbar`.

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari Np!